# Dont see settings in xcode project

Tags: ios

I'm doing an app and i try to have a setting that the user would be able to change from the iOS Settings page,

i opened a new `settings.bundle` in my app
and kept some of the default values, but i dont see it in my actual device settings

i tried reinstalling that app many tines, and i still dont see the app settings in my settings options on my iOS

here is my settings i created:

[image]

i kept the default values in the Root.plist

[image]

but also on the simulator and also on the actually device i dont see anything on the settings

[image]

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: @Mitesh jadav what does this answer have to do with what i asked ?

Comment: [This tutorial](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/adding-settings-to-your-ios-app-cecef8c5497) says "Don’t forget to add the default values for Title. It will not appear in the settings otherwise".  Edit your question to show your the values in each item of your Root.plist.

Comment: @Michael Dautermann i tried it already, it still didn't work edited question*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official docs at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html:

> A Settings bundle has the name Settings.bundle and resides in the
>   top-level directory of your app’s bundle. This bundle contains one or
>   more Settings page files that describe the individual pages of
>   preferences. It may also include other support files needed to display
>   your preferences, such as images or localized strings. Table 4-2 lists
>   the contents of a typical Settings bundle.

So renaming your settings bundle to `Settings.bundle` should fix the problem.